# JSON-RPC within xp:repeat

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, json-rpc

In the article "Improve XPages Application Performance with JSON-RPC" Brad Balassaitis writes:

For example, if you have a repeat control with a collection named myRepeat and
a property named myProperty, you could pass/retrieve it in client-side JavaScript
with this syntax:
‘#{javascript: myRepeat.myProperty}’
Then your call to the remote method would look like this:
myRpcService.setScopeVar(‘#{javascript: myRepeat.myProperty}’);

If I look at the xp:repeat control where should I set this myProperty property?

My idea is to display values from another source within a repeat control. So for each entry in the repeat control I would like to make a call via the Remote Service control and add additional information received from the service.

Anyone achieved this before?

Answer (score 1):

JSON-RPC is just a mechanism to allow you to trigger server-side code without needing a full partial refresh. `myProperty` is not an actual property, same as `myRepeat` would not, in practice, be the name of your repeat. It's an example.

Are you wanting the user to click on something in the row in order to load additional information? That's the only use case for going down the RPC route.

If you want to show additional information not available in the current entry but based on a property of that entry, just add a control and compute the value.

In terms of optimisation, unless you're displaying hundreds of rows at a time or loading data from lots of different databases or views, each based on a property in the current row, it should be pretty quick. I would recommend getting it working, then optimise it if you find server-side performance is an issue. view.isRenderingPhase() is a good option for optimising performance of read-only data within a repeat, as is custom language to minimise the amount of HTML pushed to the browser, and also using a dataContext to ensure you only do the lookup to e.g. another document once. But if the network requests to and from the server are slow, optimising the server-side code to shave a fraction of a second on processing will have not have a very perceptible impact.

Comment: Are you wanting the user to click on something in the row in order to load additional information? That's the only use case for going down the RPC route. -> Why this limitation?

Comment: Because the RPC is a user-triggered event. You're running a procedure (specific SSJS code) remotely (from CSJS triggered by a user click / blur / focus event in the browser). If you want the user to load information at their request, RPC may be appropriate, but I'm not totally sure how the RPC passes the result back to the browser. If you want the information already available for them, just compute it on your XPage design and set rendered as appropriate, if required.

Comment: I was considering the onLoad event (or document.ready) which I consider a user-triggered event (loading a page)...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm struggling to understand why you would make a *second* request to the server immediately after the page is loaded, unless something can have changed between the server delivering the HTML for the page and that second request being made. If it's on page load, just compute it all on the XPage, which should have access to everything you need, since you can do subsequent computations within a repeat control based on properties of the current row entry.